# c# Variable Declaration

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

I'm building a console application on visual studio that involves some SQL. Basically, I have a database table with a large amount of columns, and I need set them as variables and have a way of addressing them efficiently. Right now I'm thinking an array which I can then loop through. Here's sort of what my code looks like right now:

```
SqlCommand getColumns = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName", 
connection1);

myReader = getColumns.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    string[] array = new string { myReader["ColumnName"].ToString(), 
    myReader["ColumnName2"].ToString, etc...};

    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        some action...array[i];
    }
}
```

I admit I'm somewhat new to c# and this kind of development, so let me know if there's a more efficient way to do this or if I need to post more code. Thanks!

Comment: There is a class named DataTable. It is a glorified array with Rows and Column. Easy to fill one from a DataReader https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Are you just asking if you should use arrays to read from a database?  I suppose you *could*, there's nothing stopping you.  Though it could become problematic in a number of ways.  Why not create a class which represents a record in the data?  Including the correct types, any data validations you need, any operations that would be performed, etc.  Then in your `while` loop you just create instances of that class from each record and add them to an overall array (or `List<T>`) of that class?

Comment: How many rows are you expecting?

Comment: My issue is that I'm getting errors in my code the way it is currently set up. There are 40+ columns and about 5,000 rows.

Comment: _getting errors_ doesn't even start to describe your problem. Please be more specific when you search help on errors that only you are able to see (we don't have your data)

Comment: However _for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)_ is surely an IndexOutOfRange exception

Comment: @A.Long: There's nothing inherently limiting about the numbers 40 or 5,000.  If you have code which is producing errors and you want our help with that, at the very least you're going to need to show that code and the errors.  The pseudo-code you have in the question wouldn't compile.  So if that *is* your code, then what you have are syntax errors on lines like `some action...array[i];` because that's not valid code.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of columns, accessing them by index instead of name would be more efficient:

```
string[] array = new string[myReader.FieldCount];
for(int i=0; i<myReader.FieldCount; i++)
{
  array[i] = myReader[i].ToString();
}
```

Also, if you know the number of columns in advance (which is usually the case), you could move array declaration out of while(myReader.Read()), resulting in less memory allocation due to reusing same array.

Another suggestion is that you might not want to convert everything to string... Declare array of objects and handle each data type as you wish. Integer probably should be assined to some entity's integer property instead of saving in string array.

Personally I would declare some entity and declare a List of those. Then populate the list from database:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    //Other properties

}

//...

SqlCommand getColumns = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName", 
connection1);

var myDataFromTable = new List<MyEntity>();

myReader = getColumns.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    myDataFromTable.Add(new MyEntity {
            Name = myReader[0] as string,
            Age = (int)myReader[1]
            //...
        });
}
//Process your list of entities here
```

Another approach may be not to save everything into memory (as you do now), but process data on the fly - everything depends on your requirements and the size of data set. But anyway I recommend parsing data to some entity and work with that.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need custom type for this. .NET already gives you `DataSet` and `DataTable`. You need `DataTable` since it's just one result set, and results look just as same as you see in SSMS results window.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(myReader);
```

Comment: Given the size of the OP's data set they don't want to pull the whole thing into memory, it's far preferable to stream the data and work on each row one at a time.

Comment: That's a design choice whether to retrieve data in sets vs all in one query. OP hasn't mentioned anything about that. Question is about how to hold so many columns rather than how to hold those many rows.

Comment: Yes, and the OP made the *specific* design choice to stream the data, because they have a lot of it, and asked a question about how to process the data that they're streaming, and you've suggested making the whole code *dramatically* worse by pulling a very large data set entirely into memory, when it wasn't previously, for zero value added.  You don't just go around making code objectively worse just "because you felt like it".

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding - On way of doing it.
We can create a class containing properties similar to that of columns in table. In the while loop you can create object of that class, then set the properties with the respected columns and add that object to Arraylist (Arraylist containing the class objects ).

Reference Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope its helps.